# XSLT - add nodes to whitespace

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have following xml

```
<session id="1" type="spaceTest">
    <p>sentencewithnospace</p>
    <p>sentence          withtenspace</p>
    <p>sentence withonetab</p>
    <p>sentence                                     withtentabs</p>
</session>
```

My requirement is add `<s>` node to `space` and add  node to tab. and id there consecutive space or tab exist, number of consecutive space or tabs should show as attribute of `<s>` or `<t>` node. so the output should be,

```
<session id="1" type="spaceTest">
        <p>sentencewithnospace</p>
        <p>sentence<s c="10"/>          withtenspace</p>
        <p>sentence<t c="1"/>   withonetab</p>
        <p>sentence<t c="10"/>                                      withtentabs</p>
    </session>
```

I've written following xsl to achieve this task,

```
<xsl:template match="p/text()" priority="10">
    <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="&#x0020;+|&#x9;+">
      <xsl:matching-substring>
        <xsl:if test="'&#x0020;'">
          <s c="{string-length()}"/>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="'&#x9;'">
          <t c="{string-length()}"/>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:matching-substring>
      <xsl:non-matching-substring>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:non-matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
</template>
```

but this gives me following output,

```
<session id="1" type="spaceTest">
    <p>sentencewithnospace</p>
    <p>sentence<s c="10"/><t c="10"/>          withtenspace</p>
    <p>sentence<s c="1"/><t c="1"/> withonetab</p>
    <p>sentence<s c="10"/><t c="10"/>                                       withtentabs</p>
</session>
```

As shown above it gives me both  and  node for space and tab.I'm new to xslt and I wonder my code structure is or not. Can you suggest me how I can do this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The check `<xsl:if test="'&#x0020;'">` always returns true as it simply converts the non-empty string `'&#x0020;'` to the boolean true. Try `<xsl:if test="contains(., '&#x0020;')">`.